# C# Reflection reference to another class from inside a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I have 2 classes, one is a DLL and the other is a .cs File and i want to call a Method in the .cs File from the DLL.

DLL

```
namespace SimpleDebugFormatting
{
    public static class DebugLog
    {
        private static Type debugFormat;
        private static Type DebugFormat
        {
            get
            {
                if (debugFormat == null)
                    return debugFormat = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(_Type => _Type.Name.Contains("DebugFormat"));

                return debugFormat;
            }
        }

        public static List<string> GetMessages(IEnumerable _Parameters)
        {
            return (List<string>)DebugFormat.GetMethod("ConcatMessages", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(DebugFormat, new object[] { _Parameters });
        }
    }
}
```

.cs File

```
namespace SimpleDebugFormatting
{
    internal static class DebugFormat
    {
        internal static List<string> ConcatMessages(object[] _Messages) { }
    }
}
```

When both classes are .cs files it all works fine, but when the "DebugLog"-class is a DLL it can't find the "DebugFormat"-class.

When i try to print all types in the DLL's assembly with

"*Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()*",

it only shows these 2:

```
SimpleDebugFormatting.DebugLog
SimpleDebugFormatting.DebugLog+<>c
```

Why is that so and how can i get it to work?

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()` what do you think it does? Why do you think that you could list types from another assembly with this ?

Comment: You would do well to use better terminology. Dll-files are one type of *assembly*, exe-files being another. All classes are part of one assembly or another after compilation. Assemblies are usually produced from a *project*. So "one is a DLL and the other is a .cs File" does not really make sense. You probably mean the classes are part of different projects/assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this:

```
private static Type DebugFormat
{
    get
    {
        if (debugFormat == null)
            return debugFormat = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(
                _Assembly => _Assembly.FullName.Contains("SimpleDebugFormattingAssembly")).GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(
                _Type => _Type.Name.Contains("DebugFormat"));

        return debugFormat;
    }
}
```

@JonasH, @Selvin, thx for the quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DebugFormat` class is marked as [internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly, as in this example:

So, you specifically asked `DebugFormat` not to be accessible by `DebugLog`. Make it public if you want it to be accessible.

Comment: Not true ... [GetTypes will return internal types too](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2y9ERQ) ... the problem is that it is in different assebly

Comment: Making it public didn't work, it still can't find the class.

Comment: @Mark H. Do you have a reference to the other assembly?

Comment: @JonasH Nope, no reference

Comment: @Mark H. well, then that is your problem, you need to reference all assemblies you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar situation, and I found the class in this way. Write down the code to help not only the questioner but also others who see this article.

```
    public static Type DebugFormat
    {
        get
        {
            if (debugFormat == null)
            {
               return debugFormat = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(
                        _Assembly => _Assembly.FullName.Contains("Assembly-CSharp")).GetTypes()
                   .FirstOrDefault(_Type => _Type.Name.Contains("namespace.classname"));
            }
            return debugFormat;
        }
    }
```

Sorry for not being good at English In addition, I also wrote a method to use regarding GetType()

```
Type assemblyType = Type.GetType("namespace.classname, Assembly-CSharp");
```